# Deleting entry from table SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to know what is the difference between these two code:

```
this.getReadbleDatabase().delete(...);
```

```
this.getWritableDatabase().delete();
```

Mention that I know that deleting entry in sqlite should be done by the `getWritableDatabase().delete();`

Please explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()) explain the difference pretty clearly:

> Create and/or open a database. This will be the same object returned
>   by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk,
>   requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a
>   read-only database object will be returned. If the problem is fixed, a
>   future call to getWritableDatabase() may succeed, in which case the
>   read-only database object will be closed and the read/write object
>   will be returned in the future.

Comment: thanks n but to delete some entry we do it by the writable or the readable because the delete methode exists in both ?

Comment: I'd call delete on the database you get back from `getReadableDatabase()` because that'll help you handle any errors that may arise when you're trying to modify the database.

Comment: As @kmdupr33 says, it doesn't make any difference.  Most of the time, the two different calls return exactly the same object.  In the *only* case in which they do not return the same object, your call to delete() will fail regardless of which one you use.  Fuggedaboudit.

Answer (score 0):

`getReadableDatabase()` returns a read-only database **only** if conditions like low memory force it to return a read-only database. In all other cases, it will return the exact same database as `getWritableDatabase()` on which you can perform all your CRUD actions.